# Error in abstract class code

Tags: c++, oop

Can we make a class abstract without making its member function pure virtual? And does abstract class has any data member?
For example:

```
class electronic
{
    int a;
    char b;
public:
    virtual void specifications() = 0;
};
```

Is this an abstract class?

Comment: If you have a single pure virtual function, like `specifications` in the example you show, then the class is abstract. That includes pure virtual function you inherit. If you don't have *any* pure virtual functions in a class (including inheritance) then the class is not abstract.

Comment: Can you either change your question title, or be more specific about that error you're talking about. The code example you show is perfectly fine,. besides the compiler may wan you about a missing virtual destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we make a class abstract without making its member function pure virtual?? and does abstract class has any data member?

There's a technique to use `protected` constructors to require that only inherited classes can be publicly instantiated. But that's not making the base class actually *abstract*.
And yes, abstract classes may contain any number of data members.

> Is this a abstract class?

Yes classes containing at least one *pure `virtual` function* are *abstract* classes.

Inheriting classes must implement the *pure `virtual` function* or these are *abstract* classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

A class is abstract as soon it is has pure virtual members, like `specifications` in your example.

This does not mean it cannot have any other members. It can have implemented member functions, it can have member variables, just as any other class. Just being abstract does not restrict anything in the class, except that you can't create instances of an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class is the class that has one or more pure virtual methods. Abstract class can have data members.